# Qt action won't connect to slot

Tags: c++, qt

Writing a school project in c++ and qt. It is supposed to be a block editor (like draw.io). I generate blocks as a buttons and setting them to a grid. Each button is supposed to have own menu to be able to get edited, deleted, etc. (image example:

[image]

We are encountering a problem, that our action won't connect to a slot. Function akceAkce is supposed only to print 1 onto output (via qInfo). But when I click on the menu button, it does nothing. Any suggestions appreciated. Thanks!

```
void BlockItem::createButton() {

    this->button = new QPushButton("+");

    this->buttonMenu = new QMenu(this->button);

    this->connectBlocks = new QAction(tr("Connect"), this->buttonMenu);

    connect(this->connectBlocks, &QAction::triggered, this, &BlockItem::akceAkce);

    this->buttonMenu->addAction(this->connectBlocks);


    this->button->setMenu(this->buttonMenu);
}

void BlockItem::akceAkce() { 
    qInfo("1"); 
}
```

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: Why the overuse of `this->`. Are the likes of `button` and `buttonMenu` members of `BlockItem` ? and I presume that `connectBlocks` is a `QAction` ?

Comment: @VishaalShankar The overuse of `this->` is because it is a variable of each instance of class `BlockItem`. `button` `buttonMenu` and `connectBlocks` are members of `BlockItem`. `connectBlocks` is an action.

Comment: @RobinVysloužil : You don't need to ! `BlockItem` members will be accessible within it's scope. Is the function `akceAkce` declared as a `slot` in the header file ?

Comment: @VishaalShankar oh nice! it had crashed without `this->` before, now it doesn't. Interensting. Thanks, man!
Yes, `akceAkce` is declared as a private slot.

Comment: Another thing would be that, I doubt if `buttonMenu` should be the parent of the `QAction` that you are creating. It should be the `BlockItem`/`this` instead. But, not sure if that will have any impact on your problem to be honest.

Comment: @VishaalShankar We've tried that before with `this` as a parent, but afterwards the menu shows empty menu only (image example: sorry about the project name https://imgur.com/a/J8Doc9Q)

Comment: If your functor-based connection compiled without any warning then I'd check whether the `QAction::triggered` signal is actually being fired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a possible explanation: you put the `BlockItem` instance on the stack, and it's going out of scope somewhere in your code, and destroyed consequently, while the push button, menu and action all survive it, since they're instantiated with `new`, thus they live on the heap.

Something like this:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    BlockItem blockitem;
    blockitem.createButton();

    ui->gridLayout->addWidget(blockitem.getButton());
}
```

In the sample code above, `blockitem` goes out of scope at the end of the method, so it is destroyed and the connection loses its receiver side (i.e. breaks).

The same would happen if you instantiate a `BlockItem` object on the heap, using `new`, but accidentally delete it somewhere. Again, the signal sender (the `QAction` object) survives the receiver and the connection is broken.

Comment: thank you, sir! you were right about the bad type of allocating (stack/heap).